# Is it possible to get rid of this information box?

Tags: front-end, interface

When you hover over a command, Mathematica gives you an option to access help:

[image]

I never ever use this; and about 2 or 3 times each hour I accidentally click on this and Mathematica freezes while it opens the help menu. This is really irritating.

Is there a way to get rid of this?

Comment: Sometime where I simply double-click on a Mathematica keyword to select it, instead of extending the selection to the word, Mathematica opens the help windows. Very unpleasant. For this reason I also want to get rid of this "option to access help".

Comment: @andre [This one worked for me](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/77528/22432)

Comment: @axsvI77 I use mathematica 11.0 Windows 7. This seems to be a solution for linux. Otherwise I haye tried all the other proposed solutions but none of them works. See my comment under [the question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/52406/5467).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the Options Inspector and navigate to "ShowCodeAssist" and clear its check mark, as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this also switches off the autocomplete drop-down list. Is it possible to keep the autocomplete but to turn off the information box shown in the question?

Comment: Agree with @AlexeyPopkov ; any way to keep the autocomplete?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov You can turn that box off (while keeping the code assist stuff on) by disabling the floating element. There are different ways of doing that described in the answers to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/52406/18476).

Comment: @Karsten 7 None of the solutions proposed in [the question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/52406/5467) works for me. See my comment below the question (Mathematica 11.0 Windows 7)