# Problem with ShowCodeAssist for getting help for a command

Tags: front-end, notebooks, version-11.2

I am running Mathematica 11.2 on Windows.

Since some days I have the following problem: when I move the mouse curser over a command no pop up help is shown.

I found the following related [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52406/how-to-disable-the-small-pop-up-windows-when-mouse-is-over-a-mathematica-command/52408#52408): in my case `ShowCodeAssist` is aeready  set to True.

I also reinstalled Mathematica, without success.

What could be the problem?
[image]

Comment: If you didn't delete `$UserBaseDirectory` yet try that and restart mathematica

Comment: In my case $UserBaseDirectory exists. I deleted there everything, restarted Mathematica and the problem is solved ... thank you.