# How to extract a list of available Method-s

Tags: options, documentation

The option `Method`applies for several functions, such as `NDSolve`, `FindRoot`, `NIntegrate` and some others. It is difficult, however, to find a list of `Method`s for a given function. By digging through tutorials I extracted, for example, a list of `Method`s for `NIntegrate`:

"GlobalAdaptive"

"ClenshawCurtisRule"

"NewtonCotesRule",

"GaussKronrodRule",

"ClenshawCurtisRule"

"MultidimensionalRule"

"GaussKronrodRule",

"LobattoKronrodRule"

"SingularityHandler"

"DuffyCoordinates"

"Trapezoidal"

"AdaptiveMonteCarlo"

BDoubleExponentialOscillatory

MultiPeriodic,

MonteCarlo,

QuasiMonteCarlo,

AdaptiveQuasiMonteCarlo

ExtrapolatingOscillatory,

MultiPeriodicDoubleExponentialOscillator,

DoubleExponentialOscillatory

though I am not sure that my collection is complete.

Is there a way to get a complete list of `Method`s for a given function? I mean not only `NIntegrate`but also others.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get a list of allowed values for an option?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19529/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-allowed-values-for-an-option)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I use this [function](http://12000.org/my_notes/faq/mma_notes/MMA.htm#x1-10400083)

```
 getList[name_String] := Module[{options, idx}, options = Names[name <> "`*"];
   options = ToExpression /@ options;
   options = {#, Options[#]} & /@ options;
   idx = Range[Length[options]];
   options = {#[[1]], TableForm[#[[2]]]} & /@ options;
   options = Insert[options[[#]], #, 1] & /@ idx;
   options = Insert[options, {"#", "Option", "Options to this option"}, 1]
   ];
```

To use:

```
r = getList["NIntegrate"];
Grid[r, Frame -> All, Alignment -> Left, FrameStyle -> Directive[Thickness[.005], 
   Gray]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I modified the above a bit based on function I think I got from one of the [Mathematica Guide books](http://www.mathematicaguidebooks.org/) but I do not remember now which book it was. The methods can be seen under the third column there by looking for `Method->` there. At least this is much easier than having to scan pages and pages of help looking for these things.

Replace the name of the command above to get other functions. To filter the `Method->` part automatically, one possible way would be to use Cases or some pattern on the result `r` above. This is left as an exercise for the pattern experts out there.

**Update**
Response to comment below. I made new version called `getList2` which only shows up the options with `Method` on them. I am sure this could be written better, but I am not good with patterns. Here we go

```
getList2[name_String] := Module[{options, idx,z1,z2},
   options = Names[name <> "`*"];
   options = ToExpression /@ options;
   options = Flatten[Last@Reap@Do[z1 = Options[options[[i]]];           
        If[z1 != {},
         z2 = Cases[z1, Rule["Method", x_] :> Method -> x];
         If[Length[z2] != 0 , Sow[{options[[i]], z2}]]
         ],
        {i, Length[options]}
        ], 1];
   (* rest for formatting*)
   idx = Range[Length[options]];
   options = {#[[1]], TableForm[#[[2]]]} & /@ options;
   options = Insert[options[[#]], #, 1] & /@ idx;
   options = Insert[options, {"#", "Option", "Options to this option"}, 1]];
```

Example calls

```
r = getList2["NIntegrate"];
Grid[r, Frame -> All, Alignment -> Left]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
r = getList2["NDSolve"];
Grid[r, Frame -> All, Alignment -> Left]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you, it is a very valuable answer. Could you please comment on your function. I could not understand, where from it knows that among all options the Method should be chosen?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I've added another function to filter only those options which has the `Method->` on them and only show those. I kept the original function as is.

Comment: Oddly, this does not work for ´Asymptotic´.