# Method options for DensityPlot and ContourPlot

Tags: plotting, options

What `Method` options are allowed for `DensityPlot` and `ContourPlot`?  I am unable to find this information either in MMA documentation or in SE.  Thanks.

Comment: Related: [How to extract a list of available Method-s](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65680/18476)

Comment: @Karsten7,@Nasser, I tried the approach you recommended but received no `Options` for `"DensityPlot"` or `"ContourPlot"`, even though with `"NIntegrate`" it worked fine.  Suggestions?

Comment: `AbsoluteOptions[
 DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}],
 Method
 ]` gives `{Method -> {"DefaultBoundaryStyle" -> Automatic,
"DefaultPlotStyle" -> Automatic, "ScalingFunctions" -> None}}`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As far as I know there is no documented list of `Method` options for `ContourPlot` and `DensityPlot`. If you want to experiment there is a large list of strings in `` Charting`CommonDump`$VisualizationMethodOptions `` to have a look at. Some of these are option settings, some are option values. Most seem to have no effect on a simple `ContourPlot` and probably  apply to different visualization functions or only apply in specific circumstances.

For an example here are a couple that affect the creation of the mesh:

```
GraphicsRow[
 ContourPlot[Sin[x y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
    Mesh -> All, PlotPoints -> 5, Method -> {#}] & /@
  {Automatic, "Subdivision" -> "Loop", "PolygonReduction" -> 100}]
```

[image]

This is the complete list:

```
{"ScalingFunctions", "PlotRandomSeed", "DraftRendering", "ArrayPlot", 
"InvertNormalsDirection", "BoundaryOffset", "Refinement", 
"MeshBoundaryValues", "StepsJoined", "SurfaceStitch", 
"UnboundedPolygons", "InterpolateMesh", "DownsampleWindow", 
"FilterMeshAll", "OriginalCoordinates", "ReturnMeshObject", 
"ReturnRawMeshObject", "MeshMaxRecursion", "ContourMaxRecursion", 
"DelaunayDomainScaling", "PolygonReverse", "VertexAliasTolerance", 
"Average", "Fan", "Seidel", "Constrained", "GradientAligned", 
"MeshRegions", "PathPolygons", "SimplifyPaths", 
"PackGraphicsComplex", "SnapContourVertex", "PlotTheme", 
"VertexColorsPalette", "VectorBackgroundPadding", "ReturnImage", 
"Closed3DRegion", "PolygonColoring", "Equalized", "EqualizeColor", 
"ColorFunctionData", "Valence", "Laplace", "Conformal", 
"RGBColorSpace", "GrayColorSpace", "ParallelPlotEvaluate", 
"ParallelPlotMethod", "ParallelPlotParameters", "LightingMethod", 
"DiffuseReflection", "AspectBasedShading", "Contrast", "Brightness", 
"Saturation", "SpatialResolution", "ElevationDefault", 
"IlluminationModel", "AngularDistanceRadius", "UseNumericalFunction", 
"NumericalFunction", "FlattenFunctions", "SuppressMessages", 
"MessagesHead", "MappingFunctions", "DomainMappingFunctions", 
"LegacyColorFunctionProcessing", "ContourShadingPrefixFunction", 
"ContoursPrefixFunction", "UseCaching", "CutMeshLines", 
"FillBoundaryLines", "Ungroup", "CloseMeshThickness", 
"ClipNoneMeshShading", "ClipAtPlotRange", "ClipMeshOverlay", 
"ClipBoundaryLines", "Subdivision", "CellDecomposition", "Divisions", 
"ControlValue", "VertexTolerance", "MaxBoundaryEdgeLength", 
"CellCuboids", "Dihedral", "Gaussian", "GradientNorm", "Loop", 
"Contouring", "Curvature", "ContourLevel", "PlanarRectangular", 
"Triangular", "Quad", "QuadTriangular", "Length", "Area", 
"Perimeter", "BhatiaLawrence", "AverageNormal", "WeightedNormal", 
"Barycenter", "Cotangents", "Circumcenter", "Incenter", "Inradius", 
"Circumradius", "InteriorAngles", "Dual", "OFF", "NOFF", "Frenet", 
"NaturalNeighbour", "InverseDistance", "Kriging", "MaxMemoryUse", 
"Intersect", "FullLattice", "MarchingCubes", "AdvancedMarchingCubes", 
"AdaptiveTriangular", "Octree", "OctreeCubes", "Algebraic", 
"Cubical", "Tetra", "Seeds", "Linear", "Bisect", "NoiseDelta", 
"ContourSpacing", "MeshSpacing", "Quantile", "CurveLength", 
"ArcLength", "DataLineMesh", "DataPointMesh", "GraphicsIndex", 
"SymbolicPiecewiseSubdivision", "pw", "PiecewiseTimeConstraint", 
"SymbolicPointsTimeConstraint", "Singularities", "Isolated", 
"SingularCurves", "SingularMaxRecursion", "ExclusionsOffset", 
"PolygonReduction", "Polygons", "PolygonContraction", 
"PointPlacement", "QuadricWeighting", "CompactnessRatio", 
"MeshPenalty", "BoundaryWeight", "EndPoint", "EndOrMidPoint", 
"LinearPoint", "OptimalPoint", "UniformWeight", "AreaWeight", 
"AngleWeight", "AverageWeight", "AreaAverageWeight", "NormalWeight", 
"VerticesGoal", "EdgesDistanceGoal", "MinArea", 
"PreserveInteriorFaces", "SegmentPartition", "SegmentLengthGoal", 
"LegendsFunction", "Legend", "Extrapolation", "Interpolation", 
"PointsToSpheres", "Caps", "ConnectEnds", "StreamlinesMethod", 
"StreamlinesSamplingStep", "StreamlinesInsertionStep", 
"StreamlinesParameterLimit", "StreamlinesNDSolve", 
"StreamlinesNumericalFunction", "LICLines", "LICMinHits", 
"LICMaxLines", "AccuracyGoal", "PrecisionGoal", "HSBChannel", 
"LICModulate", "NewtonFlow", "PerturbateFrame", "PerturbateSeeds", 
"ParseGlyphStyle", "LinePath", "LineArrow", "GlyphPath", 
"Directional", "DirectionalScaled", "Velocity", "VelocityScaled", 
"ControlPoints", "BSplineCurve", "BezierCurve", "NURBSCurve", 
"XSplineCurve", "BSplineShape", "BezierShape", "NURBSShape", 
"XSplineShape", "SharedMemoryReference", "Method", "Automatic", 
"None", "All", "True", "False"}
```

Comment: How did you obtain this list?  Thanks.

Comment: Man, this is awesome! Thanks!
Could you elaborate on how you found the corresponding control stringt like the "Loop" in your given example? Was this just straight up trying?

Edit: I found the refinement method suuuuper helpful to fine tune the meshing used in density and contour plots. 
Use with _Method->{"Refinement" -> {"ControlValue" -> 3 Degree}}_  ... together with MaxRecursion and PlotPoints one can find a very nice local adaptive sampling in most cases

Comment: I think it was just automated trying different combinations and seeing which ones changed the output.

Answer (score 1):

One should not be confused with method or option.

A method in the sense of Mathematica (See: [Method](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Method.html))

[image]

Options in the sense of Mathematica (See: [Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Options.html))

[image]

For `DensityPlot` or `ContourPlot` you can query for Options with `??DensityPlot` or with `??ContourPlot`:

[image]

The [Link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65680/how-to-extract-a-list-of-available-method-s) provided by @Karsten 7. (answer by @Nasser), is a really fabulous strategy to "unearth" the methods to a function.

For example (algorithm omitted) with:

```
r = getList2["NDSolve"];
Grid[r, Frame -> All, Alignment -> Left]
```

all "Methods" approved for NDSolve are listed:

[image]

**Edit**

Since DensityPlot, ContourPlot and others have the same options as Graphics those rules are applicable (see [Graphics](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) and see "The following Method options can be given" ibid. For Functions Mathematica states:

> With the default setting Method->Automatic, the Wolfram Language will
>   automatically try to pick the best method for a particular
>   computation.

See [Method](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Method.html).

Comment: I agree that "the link provided by @Karsten 7. (answer by @Nasser), is a really fabulous strategy to "unearth" the methods to a function."  However, although it works well for `"NDSolve"` and `"NIntegrate"`, it returns no useful information for `"DensityPlot"` or `"ContourPlot"`.

Comment: True, but with ??ContourPlot you will retrieve all Options aviable, hence "Method" is only applicable to Functions with Method.

Comment: indeed, `??ContourPlot`, like `Options[ContourPlot]`, returns a long list of options, including `Method->Automatic`.  I wish to know what those methods are.  (@Karsten7 identifies some of them in an earlier comment.)  I should add that @Nasser provides two functions, `getList` and `getList2`.  Neither returns information for "DensityPlot" or "ContourPlot".