# "Kriging" plot method?

Tags: plotting

What does "Kriging" method for plotting do? Could someone show an example? Has it anything to do with the geostatistical interpolation method (Wiener-Kolmogorov prediction)?
I bumped into it [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69448/method-options-for-densityplot-and-contourplot/69486#69486) and it seams like a method in `Plot` function.

Comment: See [Kriging In Mathematica](http://www.geostatisticskitchen.com/geoblog/kriginginmathematica)

Comment: It looks like a package. I asked about the "method" in Plot function.