# How to know the string data/settings, of some options/functions

Tags: functions, options

It is known that several functions and options take some sort of input in this form:

```
option->"something"
function["something"]
```

The simple example for this is the `PlotTheme`  in plot:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotTheme -> "Marketing"];
```

Another example is:

```
Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, VertexShapeFunction -> "Square"];
```

Some functions have an input in the same manner

For example:

```
GraphElementData["GraphStyle"];
```

My questions are:

1- what are these `"something"` called. I have seen some places they are called settings and some other places called data.

2- How can I search these `"something"`. Most of them are not in the documentation and also some options and functions does not list all of its such input in the documentation.

**3- How can I list all of these "something" that an option or function can have as input.**

I hope I can get a detailed answer for this

Thank you

Comment: I recall someone posting some code for this a few years ago. It may have been @Nasser. If he does not reply I will see if I can dig it up

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch It was this [how-to-extract-a-list-of-available-method-s](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65680/how-to-extract-a-list-of-available-method-s) but it does not work on the above examples. I just tried it.

Comment: @Nasser thanks. re-reading your post I now remember that your code was written for Method options. It looks like something that could be re-written for this question though?

Comment: As you type `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotTheme ->` a pop-up selection menu will appear with the valid entries. Similarly for `Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, VertexShapeFunction ->`

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch `It looks like something that could be re-written for this question though?` that might be possible. I do not know now. When finals are over, will see if I can change it to do what is being asked here. Unless someone has a better answer meanwhile.

Comment: Related or possible duplicates: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78935/18476 and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/809/18476.