# Writing functions with "Method" options

Tags: function-construction, options, coding-style

I'd like to implement several behaviors for a particular function using a `Method` option added to the function definition:

```
Options[saveData] = {Method -> "Addition"};
saveData[vars_, opts : OptionsPattern[{saveData}]] := 
  saveData[vars, OptionValue[Method]]
saveData[vars_, "Addition"] := Total @ vars
saveData[vars_, "Multiplication"] := Times @@ vars

saveData[{1, 2, 3}, Method->"Multiplication"]
(* 6 *)
saveData[{a, b, c}, Method->"Addition"]
(* a + b + c *)
```

This seems to work alright, but is probably clunky or fragile in ways that haven't occurred to me. I've seen a number of built-in commands that take this sort of `Method` option to run different approaches on the same problem. What are good (robust?, simple?, efficient?) patterns for doing this kind of code-switching?

See also: [[How to extract a list of available Method-s](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65680) ]

Comment: If each method has a sufficiently complex implementation, I would have done the same thing; no sense trying to stuff all the complexity into a single monolith.

Comment: @dionys Do you plan to pass sub-options to the method option? E.g. `saveData[someVars, Method->{"Addition",Method->"CompensatedSummation"}]`.

Comment: @AntonAntonov Maybe you can give a answer to demonstrate the strategy/solution that the built-in used with the developer's perspective.:)

Comment: @ShutaoTANG Thanks for the suggestion! I consider posting an answer to this question in the next few days.

Comment: @AntonAntonov Looking forward to your constructive answer.

Comment: @AntonAntonov passing sub-options would be a nice improvement, but I'd like to keep the machinery as simple as I can so it can be maintained easily. I'm also looking forward to your answer.

Answer (score 18):

### Introduction

> What are good (robust?, simple?, efficient?) patterns for doing this
>   kind of code-switching?

This answer outlines a development strategy that can produce robust and extensible method option handling. Conceptually and development-wise, it is not that simple, but it has been successfully applied in large software projects with complicated dependencies between the algorithms and their corresponding specifications. The options of `NIntegrate` are a very good example.

(Note that as it was indicated in the comments of the question post, simpler option structures are of interest for OP. )

The main idea is to treat the option values given to `Method` as sentences from a [Domain Specific Language (DSL)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/110129/34008). One good way to explain this approach is to use of the design pattern [Interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern) as a reference, see [GoF94]. The approach is robust because it allows easy extension of the grammar, and easy addition and/or variation of the interpretations of its sentences (option specifications in this case).

For more a general discussion of DSL design and interpretation see [this MSE answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/110129/34008). (Alternatively, see [AADSL16].)

### Set-up

Given the example in the question formulation let us assume that we want both `saveData` methods `"Addition"` and `"Multiplication"` to take the option `"Delimiter"` and `"Addition"` to also take the method sub-option `"CompensatedSummation"` (which is an option of `Total`). `"CompensatedSummation"` can take options on its own, say, `"WorkingPrecision"`.

### Strategy steps

#### Grammar design

First, we come up with a grammar for the `Method` option. Here is an example using [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus_Naur_Form) :

```
 <method-opt> = ( 'Method' , <rule-arrow> ) | ( <opt-spec> | <core-method> ) ;
 <opt-head> = 'Method' | 'WorkingPrecision' | 'Delimiter' ;
 <core-method> = 'Addition' | 'Multiplication' | 'CompensatedSummation' ;
 <opt-rule> = <opt-head> , <rule-arrow> | ( <core-method> | <opt-value> | <opt-spec> ) ;
 <opt-value> = '_String' ;
 <opt-spec> = '{' | <core-method> , [ ',' | <opt-list> ] | '}' ;
 <opt-list> = <opt-rule> , { ',' | <opt-rule> } ;
 <rule-arrow> = '->' | '\[Rule]' ;
```

#### Parsing

Next we make a parser for this EBNF. This can be done using ad-hoc programming or a parser creation/generation package like [FunctionalParsers.m](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/natural-language-processing-with-functional-parsers/). The parser would produce a tree for each command. Below is a table with the parsing results of multiple commands made with the above grammar. Note that we have produced trees of the option specifications that are easier to traverse using as prescribed by the design pattern *Interpreter*.

[image]

The table above was made using the package [FunctionalParsers.m](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/FunctionalParsers.m) but in the context of this answer its application is only for experimental purposes, to easily derive and try out different grammars. I think it is better the parser to be made in a more ad-hoc manner by applying the prescription of *Interpreter* to program a parser-interpreter function (or class) for each grammar rule. One benefit is that we can have better, more detailed handling of wrong options. (This is how it was done in `NIntegrate`.)

#### Interpretation

At this point we are ready to program the interpretation of the parser result trees. Those trees can be interpreted in different ways in different contexts of data and function signatures.

### Example

A real life example of applying this approach -- `NIntegrate`'s `Method` option -- is discussed in [this video](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?c=400&v=1470) between 25:00 and 27:30. For the `Method` option parsing trees produced in `NIntegrate` see the section "UPDATE" of [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96663/34008) of ["Determining which rule NIntegrate selects automatically"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26401/34008).

### Extensions

We might want to have a more elaborated grammar that does not parse incompatible combinations of methods and sub-methods. For example, in the table above the command 3:

```
"Method -> {Multiplication, Method -> {CompensatedSummation, WorkingPrecision -> 40}}"
```

is successfully parsed but we probably consider "Multiplication" and "CompensatedSummation" to be incompatible.

Similarly, the command 6:

```
"Method -> {Addition, Method -> CompensatedSummation, WorkingPrecision -> 34}"
```

is successfully parsed, but we probably want "WorkingPrecision" to be a valid option only to some of the methods of "Addition".

These observations lead us to the conclusion that the grammar was too simple and general since it allows too many incorrect sentences. At this point we need to decide (1) do we handle the incorrect sentences at the interpretation phase, or (2) do we make a more complicated grammar that allows successful parsing of only meaningful combinations.

I would say for both development directions it is better to have a rigorous grammar that allows only meaningful commands. The EBNF of such a grammar can be also seen as a compact API specification and functionality design.

Here is a such more detailed grammar:

```
 <method-opt> = ( 'Method' , <rule-arrow> ) |> <opt-spec> ;
 <opt-spec> = <add-method> | <mult-method> ;
 <opt-head> = 'Method' | 'WorkingPrecision' | 'Delimiter' ;
 <add-method> = 'Addition' | '{' | 'Addition' , [ ',' | <add-opt-list> ] | '}' ;
 <mult-method> = 'Multiplication' | '{' | 'Multiplication' , [ ',' | <mult-opt-list> ] | '}' ;
 <compsum-method> = 'CompensatedSummation' | '{' | 'CompensatedSummation' , [ ',' | <compsum-opt-list> ] | '}' ;
 <add-opt-list> = <add-opt-rule> , { ',' | <add-opt-rule> } ;
 <mult-opt-list> = <mult-opt-rule> , { ',' | <mult-opt-rule> } ;
 <compsum-opt-list> = <compsum-opt-rule> , { ',' | <compsum-opt-rule> } ;
 <add-opt-rule> = ( 'Method' | 'Delimiter' ) , <rule-arrow> | ( <opt-value> |  <compsum-method> ) ;
 <mult-opt-rule> = 'Delimiter', <rule-arrow> |> <opt-value> ;
 <compsum-opt-rule> = 'WorkingPrecision', <rule-arrow> | <opt-value> ;
 <opt-value> = '_String' ;
 <rule-arrow> = '->' | '\[Rule]' ;
```

### References

[GoF94] Erich Gamma, Richard Helm, Ralph Johnson, John Vlissides, [Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns), 1994, Addison-Wesley.

[AADSL16] Anton Antonov, ["Creating and programming DSLs"](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2016/03/22/creating-and-programming-dsls/), (2016), [MathematicaForPrediction blog at WordPress](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/).

[AAFP] Anton Antonov, [Functional Parsers topic](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/category/functional-parsers) at [MathematicaForPrediction blog at WordPress](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I would like to know that which file should I save for the **EBNF** defintions.

Comment: @ShutaoTANG **(1)** "Thanks for your detailed explanation." - Sure! **(2)** "[...] which file should I save for the EBNF" - I am not sure what do you mean. You can use text files for EBNFs. In Mathematica, I just assign EBNF grammars to strings.

Comment: If I write the **EBNF** defintion in the *Mathematica* notebook or `*.m` file, *Mathematica* will show [syntax error](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tqR3G.png)

Comment: @ShutaoTANG As I mentioned, in Mathematica you can use strings for EBNF.

Answer (score 9):

Normally this would be comment. but I post it here so there will be an answer.

There is nothing wrong with the way you implemented your function. Your code is robust, simple, and efficient and IMO follows good *Mathematica* functional programming style.

Answer (score 6):

In general, I using the following strategy:

- Using a varible `$MethodValues` to store all the possible method value.
- Using `If[]` and `Return[$Failed]` to check the validness of method value that user given, which can make the code more robust.
- Using `Switch[]/Which[]` to deal with each case.

---

```
Options[saveData] = {Method -> Automatic};
$MethodValues = {"Addition", "Multiplication", Automatic};

saveData::bdmtd = 
   "Value of Method -> `` is not one of " <> ToString@$MethodValues;

saveData[vars_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Module[{mtd},
   mtd = OptionValue[Method];
   If[! MemberQ[$MethodValues, mtd],
    Message[saveData::bdmtd, mtd];
    Return[$Failed]
   ];
   Switch[mtd,
    Automatic | "Addition",
    Total@vars,
    "Multiplication",
    Times @@ vars
   ]
 ]
```

Let's test it

```
saveData[{1, 2, 3}, Method -> "1"]
saveData[{1, 2, 3}, Method -> "Multiplication"]
saveData[{a, b, c}, Method -> "Addition"]
```

[image]

---

When the function `saveData[]` only owns a option `Method`, the OP's implementation maybe reasonable. However, when function owns many options, the OP's solution will be complicated.

Comment: Conditionals like `Which[]` would be fine if the individual cases/methods are not too complicated; otherwise you end up with a monolith that is a nightmare to read and/or maintain.

Comment: @J.M. According to my practice, the  values of `Method` option that I deal with are not too complicated. Namely, just a few of elements like `{md1,md2...,mdn}`., where $n<6$. So I would like to know how did you deal with many method value, such as `NDSolve[]`'s `Method` option?

Comment: @ShutaoTANG The implementation of the `Method` options of `NIntegrate` and `NDSolve` are discussed in [this video](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?c=400&v=1470) between 25:00 and 27:30. The  `Method` option of `NIntegrate` was designed by using the OOP design pattern Interpreter.

Comment: @AntonAntonov Thanks a bunch! Since you were a developer of **WRI** before, so I would like to know: **(1)** which language(*Wolfram Language*?) was used to implement `NIntegrate[]` or `NSolve[]`? **(2)** Recently, I have been developing a `CAGD`(*Computer Aided Geometry Design*) package, I used the *Wolfram Language* , could you give me some **advice** to improve the performance of my functions?

Comment: @ShutaoTANG **(1)** It was/is a mixture of C and Wolfram Language. **(2)** Performance for CAGD is outside of my expertise. I would say though, that using OOP Design Patterns has helped me a lot to make designs that provide good abstractions, ability for performance tuning, and transition to other developers.

Comment: @AntonAntonov If I implemented the **functions** that need high-performance in **C/java**, how to add these **external code** into my *Mathematica* package? Thanks-:)

Comment: @ShutaoTANG At least several answers to similar/same questions are given on MSE. For example, see this [LibraryLink search](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=LibraryLink).

Comment: @AntonAntonov OK, Got it :)