# How to Obtain Complete List of Properties

Tags: variable

I am working with Matrix Market matrices in Mathematica (specifically [GEMAT12](https://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/data/Harwell-Boeing/gemat/gemat12.html)), and I saw from other posts that you call properties of a variable exemplified below:

```
A = Import["gemat12.mtx"];
A["Density"]
A["Dimensions"]
```

With the following output:

```
0.00136011
{4929, 4929}
```

So my question: How can I list all available properties of my variable A?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Importing [`"MTX"`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/MTX.html) returns a [`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html), so you can do `A["Properties"]`. You don't need to manually unzip your file to have access to the `"MTX"` data.

```
Import[
    "https://math.nist.gov/pub/MatrixMarket2/Harwell-Boeing/gemat/gemat12.mtx.gz"
    , {"GZIP", "MTX" }
]["Properties"] 

(* {AdjacencyLists,BandWidth,ColumnIndices,Density,ExplicitLength,ExplicitPositions,ExplicitValues,ImplicitValue,RowPointers,ReplaceValues} *)
```

Also of interest

```
Import[
    "https://math.nist.gov/pub/MatrixMarket2/Harwell-Boeing/gemat/gemat12.mtx.gz"
    , {"GZIP", "MTX" , "Elements"}
]  

(* {Comments, Data, Graphics, MatrixStructure, Summary} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! If I may ask another quickly, how would I get a list of methods for the variable `A`? I see how to do it for functions like "Solve" from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65680/how-to-extract-a-list-of-available-method-s) but can't get it to apply to an already defined sparse matrix. EDIT: This is in regards to getting a list that includes "Properties", "Dimensions", and "NonzeroValues". I apologize if my language is confusing - I'm confused on the terminology myself.